# Webpack css-loader doesn't load css when the modules option is set to true

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, css-loader

I'm trying to import CSS as modules to a react app.
I have added this to my webpack.config.js file

```
{
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader' },
          { loader: 'css-loader', options: { modules: true } },
        ],
      },
```

This is the implementation

app.tsx

```
import styles from './styles.module.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.mainContent}>
        <h1> Hello, World! </h1>
        <Button type="primary">Antd works!</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

styles.module.css

```
.mainContent {
    color: limegreen;
}
```

But this CSS class has no effect on the
[output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIcyX.png)

Comment: Have you tried this without the `options: { modules: true }` statement?  It should work fine as is without that clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the global design of antd you can use a less loader as described in the antd docs for [custom theme with webpack config](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#Customize-in-webpack).

If you only want to change the button color you can use plain css. E.g.:

```
.ant-btn-primary {
  background: red;
  border-color: red;
}
```

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-cache-3tdi8?file=/index.css:0-60) with a custom button color.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid duplicated class names, css module transforms the class names at compilation.

so you will not be able to override css classes using css modules, because the class names will always be different from each other.

in order to override css class you need to use plain css, eg.

```
import './styles.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="mainContent">
        <h1> Hello, World! </h1>
        <Button type="primary">Antd works!</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```